# nodejs: problema con las funcionar síncronas y asíncronas

Tags: nodejs

estoy tratando de leer un archivo json, y usarlo como si fuera una variable, y poder guardar dicho archivo json para que al reiniciar la app, tenga mis datos intactos.
pienso que mi implementación esta bien, aun así no se porque no funciona, alguna idea?

```
let student ={};
const fs = require('fs');

function readUser(){
 fs.readFile('student.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    student = JSON.parse(data);
});
}

function writeUser() {
    let data2 = JSON.stringify(student);
    console.log(data2);
    fs.writeFileSync('student.json', data2);
}



readUser()
console.log(student);
console.log(student.car);
if (student.car = 'mustang') {
    student.car = "honda";
}
else{
    student.car = "mustang";
}
console.log(student.car);
writeUser();
console.log(student);
```

Comment: No funciona porque `fs.readFile` es asíncrona y el valor devuelto estará disponible en un futuro incierto al cual no tienes acceso de forma sincrona. Una solución no óptima es usar `fs.readFileSync`. Pero como digo, no es óptima, ya que bloquea el programa hasta que termina de leer el archivo. Saludos

Comment: Puedes usar `fs.promises` para usar las funciones que devuelven una promesa y así usar `aync/await` o `.then()` para esperar su resultado.

Answer (score 1):

### El Problema

Como dice en los comentarios, el problema es que `fs.readFile` es asíncrona por lo que debes esperar hasta que termine de ejecutarse para poder hacer cosas sobre el resultado.

### La solución

Para esto una posible solución es envolver `fs.readFile` en una promesa:

```javascript
const fs = require('fs');

function readUser(){
  return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile('student.json', (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });
}

function writeUser(student) {
    let data2 = JSON.stringify(student);
    console.log(data2);
    fs.writeFileSync('student.json', data2);
}

readUser()
  .then(student => {
    console.log(student);
    console.log(student.car);
    if (student.car = 'mustang') {
        student.car = "honda";
    }
    else{
        student.car = "mustang";
    }
    console.log(student.car);
    writeUser(student);
    console.log(student);
})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

### Explicación

Ahora bien, hay algunas diferencias importantes a destacar respecto a tu código original. (Primero que nada te recomiendo que leas la [documentación sobre promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise))

1. La variable "global" `let student ={};` ya no existe más. Por un lado porque no es una buena práctica tener una variable global, y por otro lado porque la funcion `function readUser()` devuelve el resultado cuando se resuelve la promesa.
2. Para usar la función `readUser()` ahora tenemos que tener en cuenta que dicha función devuelve una promesa, por lo que debemos usar `.then()` para manejar el resultado cuando se resuelva.

> Dentro del `.then()` la promesa se ha resuelto exitosamente y tenemos acceso al resultado. Por favor lee sobre promesas en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

3. Como ya no existe la variable `let student ={};`, ahora lo pasamos por parámetro `function writeUser(student)`.